# SAML wrong attribute mapping

Tags: saml, saml-2.0, openam, opensaml

I was authenticating my Service with SAML based authentication and configured the attribute as follows:

```
<Attribute name="attributeMap">
    <Value>userid=uid</Value>
    <Value>name=cn</Value>
</Attribute>
```

And was fetching it back in the following way:

```
Map attribute= (Map) map.get(SAML2Constants.ATTRIBUTE_MAP);
```

But when I access the Map the field name comes as "uid" and "cn" which is ID provider specific key,but as per the document it should come as "userid" and "name"

Comment: Which library are you using?  That might help people answer your question.

Comment: @tom I found the answer for this,actually i have defined mapping also in SP-Extended, on making it *=* solves my problem